# How to test Jasmine setup code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, testing, jasmine

***Update:*** I figured out what the issue was, see my comment below.

Is there a way to guarantee state before each Jasmine test?
For example:

```
describe('some thing', function () {
    beforeEach(function () {
        doSetup();
        // this expect does not evaluate :(
        expect(something).toBe(inSomeState);
    });
    it('has some behavior', function () {
        // test code
    });
});
```

The expect inside of the setup make no difference at all. Even throwing an error in the beforeEach does nothing. I would like to have some assurance that the setup has completed correctly before running the next test.. is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I see what the issue is. Hoping this will help other people out there having this same issue. grunt-contrib-jasmine does not display errors or failed expects inside of `beforeEach` or `afterEach` with the `display` option set to `short`. Setting this option to `full` will once again display Errors and failed expects.